# Eclipse Web Services Test Client and Exception: (401) Unauthorized error

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to test a user/pw protected web service using the "web services test client" in Eclipse IDE. I am able to generate the client but when I test any methods I get the exception: (401)Unauthorized error. How do i get about putting the username/pw authentication so that my client is able to call the functions successfully?

Thank You

Comment: Which framework are you using? CXF? Metro? Axis? Axis2?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add username password in url of webservice while accessing.

http://username:password@your_webservice_url

Comment: Can you try same url (one I proposed in my answer) through any browser ? 
Also post url used and response received.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion ? Did you get some resolution ?

Comment: please comment when down voting. That's stackoverflow ethics anyways.